# for loops in MATLAB different combinations

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am running a series of multiple regressions in the form,

$$Y_{t+1}=\alpha_1+\beta_{1}X_{1t}+\beta_2X_{2t}+\varepsilon_{t+1}$$

So I have 50 x's to chose from and different combinations of these that I want to test.

So I want to run the model, with

x20 and x20

x21 and x50

x28 and x49

as example, I have these written out and could pasted them into matlab.

```
clear; 
data = xlsread('EXCELSHEET.xlsx',1);

for (ii=3, jj=2),(ii=4, jj=5)


xinit=[data(:,ii),data(:,jj)];
yinit=[data(:,7)];

end
```

My question is how can type this in, I have around 60 combinations?

Comment: are your combinations  arbitrary? where they come from? how do you know those 60?

Comment: My combinations are not arbitrary, I am running joint hypothesis tests based on another paper! They decide the combinations.

Comment: So.... should we ask them, or are you willing to provide all the information we need to help you?

Comment: Yes, no problem! I am trying to predict corporate bond returns for an undergraduate finance class. I need to complete joint hypothesis tests in MATLAB, so I have written the code for the model, and it works fine for when I run them, individual. Two of my independent variables are fixed, two are the bond returns from companies, the original research (a working paper by my professor) links companies together and classes them as economically related. I need to add pairs of these into the model.

Comment: We need, as I asked, the combinations, or the rationale behind them.

Comment: Then the combinations are. 7 23,
45 46,
41 21,
44 30,
31 39,
44 8,
45 7,
16 36,
29 49,
19 32,
7 49,
4 39,
22 40,
27 39,
22 25,
21 21,
50 47,
43 5,
27 35,
14 8,
48 35,
38 36,
14 12,
35 47,
36 16,
22 46,
34 15,
42 34,
37 1,
11 22,
50 45,
12 45,
7 34,
33 20,
20 40,
5 17,
6 14,
22 13,
36 3,
34 16,
9 45,
19 7,
1 16,
18 38,
24 1,
21 1,
14 12,
3 44,
42 32,
24 40,
34 29,
6 6,
34 19,
14 25,
28 41,
29 4,
25 40,
44 32,
44 31,
1 11,

Comment: Maybe I am not clear. If the numbers are arbitrarily chosen (please note, not randomly, but arbitrarily, i.e. without a mathematical equation or any other rationale than "this is the way I wanted them because reasons"), then your onyl option is hard-coding them. Its irrelevant if they are candy packages or bonds.

Comment: Yes, sorry. They have been determined to be theoretically related by a professor, but he does not have a formula or anything.

Comment: I have the combinations written in excel, I was wondering of a quick way to get the output. Sorry if my question is bad, I'm just new to this and have a deadline. Thanks so much for your advice!

Comment: Stop spamming the comment section and [edit] your question with any relevant information

Comment: The comments of @AnderBiguri are hash, but right. It’s important to learn how to ask questions: provide a fully functional and minimal working example. When you ask a question on SO, you’re talking to (a collective) someone who is an excellent programmer but has no idea about your particular problem. Having said all of that; Welcome to stack overflow! I hope we can help you with your problems and in return you can help others. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are arbitrary, you need to hardcode them.

```
Myarbitrarycombinations= [7 23; 45  46; ... ];
% or read them from somewhere    

for ii=size(Myarbitrarycombinations,1)
   xinit=[data(:,Myarbitrarycombinations(ii,1)),data(:,Myarbitrarycombinations(ii,2))];
   % whatever else
end
```